# Delay update to R Shiny multiple-plot app

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to speed up an R Shiny app I'm building to explore a set of data. The app displays sentences for some of the data and a series of bar charts for other data. Each of these is rendered separately.

Every time I click one of the checkboxes, however, to filter the data, the whole thing re-renders and this takes about a second to complete. How can I isolate the rendering of all of the charts until a "go" button is clicked? I've tried a few other suggestions on SO but haven't found out how to do it with multiple renderPlots.

Sorry for the mess of code. I didn't want to shorten it too much or I'll lose some of the context.

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- read.csv("dm_survey.csv")

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$surveyPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    d <- d[d$"Frequency of Games" %in% c(input$frequency),]
    d <- d[d$"Length of Games" %in% c(input$length),]
    d <- d[d$"Primary Locations" %in% c(input$locations),]
    d <- d[d$"Campaign Worlds" %in% c(input$worlds),]
    d <- d[d$"Adventures" %in% c(input$adventures),]
    d <- d[d$"Preferred Combat Type" %in% c(input$combat),]
    d <- d[d$"Preparation Time" %in% c(input$preptime),]

    output$textmain <- renderUI(HTML("<h1>2016 D&D Dungeon Master Survey</h1>"))

    table_columns <- c("Campaign Worlds", "Primary Locations", 
                       "Adventures", 
                       "Preferred Combat Type")
    total_sentences <- c()
    for (table_column in table_columns) {
      num_respondents <- nrow(d[table_column])
      question_title <- tolower(table_column)
      sentence <- paste("Of", num_respondents, "respondents on", question_title, collapse = "")
      tbl <- data.frame(sort(table(d[table_column]),decreasing = TRUE))
      if (nrow(tbl) == 1) {
        tbl <- data.frame("Activity" = d[table_column][1,], "Count" = nrow(d),"Freq" = 100)
        print(tbl)
      } else {
        tbl["Percentage"] <- round(tbl["Freq"] / colSums(tbl["Freq"]) * 100, 0)
      }
      for(i in 1:nrow(tbl)) {
        answer_title <- tolower(as.character(tbl[i,1]))
        answer_percentage <- tbl[i,3]
        sentence <- paste(sentence, ", ", answer_percentage, "% answered ", answer_title, collapse="", sep = '')
      }
      sentence <- paste(sentence, ".", collapse="", sep = '')
      total_sentences <- c(total_sentences, sentence)
    }
    output$text1 <- renderUI(HTML(paste(total_sentences[1],"<br/><br/>")))
    output$text2 <- renderUI(HTML(paste(total_sentences[2],"<br/><br/>")))
    output$text3 <- renderUI(HTML(paste(total_sentences[3],"<br/><br/>")))
    output$text4 <- renderUI(HTML(paste(total_sentences[4],"<br/><br/>")))

    column_name <- "Frequency of Games"
    factor_labels <- c("Less than monthly","Monthly","Twice monthly","Weekly","Twice a week","More than twice weekly")
    d[,column_name] <- factor(d[,column_name], levels = factor_labels)
    p1 <- ggplot(d, aes(factor(d[,column_name])))
    p1 + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + theme_minimal() +
      scale_y_continuous(expand=c(.1, 0)) +
      labs(x = "",
           title = column_name, 
           y=paste("Number of Respondants out of",nrow(d))) +
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
                stat= "count", hjust=-.1)
  })
  output$surveyPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    d <- d[d$"Frequency of Games" %in% c(input$frequency),]
    d <- d[d$"Length of Games" %in% c(input$length),]
    d <- d[d$"Primary Locations" %in% c(input$locations),]
    d <- d[d$"Campaign Worlds" %in% c(input$worlds),]
    d <- d[d$"Adventures" %in% c(input$adventures),]
    d <- d[d$"Preferred Combat Type" %in% c(input$combat),]
    d <- d[d$"Preparation Time" %in% c(input$preptime),]
    column_name <- "Length of Games"
    factor_labels <- c("Longer than eight hours","About eight hours","About six hours","About four hours","About three hours","About two hours","About an hour")
    d[,column_name] <- factor(d[,column_name], levels = factor_labels)
    p2 <- ggplot(d, aes(factor(d[,column_name])))
    p2 + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + theme_minimal() +
      scale_y_continuous(expand=c(.1, 0)) +
      labs(x = "",
           title = column_name, 
           y=paste("Number of Respondants out of",nrow(d))) +
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
                stat= "count", hjust=-.1)
  })
  output$surveyPlot3 <- renderPlot({
    d <- d[d$"Frequency of Games" %in% c(input$frequency),]
    d <- d[d$"Length of Games" %in% c(input$length),]
    d <- d[d$"Primary Locations" %in% c(input$locations),]
    d <- d[d$"Campaign Worlds" %in% c(input$worlds),]
    d <- d[d$"Adventures" %in% c(input$adventures),]
    d <- d[d$"Preferred Combat Type" %in% c(input$combat),]
    d <- d[d$"Preparation Time" %in% c(input$preptime),]    
    column_name <- "Preparation Time"
    factor_labels <- c("More than four hours","About four hours","About three hours","About two hours","About an hour","About 30 minutes","About 15 minutes","I don't prepare at all")
    d[,column_name] <- factor(d[,column_name], levels = factor_labels)
    p3 <- ggplot(d, aes(factor(d[,column_name])))
    p3 + geom_bar() + coord_flip() + theme_minimal() +
      scale_y_continuous(expand=c(.1, 0)) +
      labs(x = "",
           title = column_name, 
           y=paste("Number of Respondants out of",nrow(d))) +
      geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
                stat= "count", hjust=-.1)

  })
  output$surveyPlot4 <- renderPlot({
    d <- d[d$"Frequency of Games" %in% c(input$frequency),]
    d <- d[d$"Length of Games" %in% c(input$length),]
    d <- d[d$"Primary Locations" %in% c(input$locations),]
    d <- d[d$"Campaign Worlds" %in% c(input$worlds),]
    d <- d[d$"Adventures" %in% c(input$adventures),]
    d <- d[d$"Preferred Combat Type" %in% c(input$combat),]
    d <- d[d$"Preparation Time" %in% c(input$preptime),]    

    # Set up a bunch of facets to show bar plots
    l <- reshape(d, 
                 varying = c("Campaign and Worldbuilding","Story and Adventures","Combat Encounters","NPC Development","Exploration and Roleplay","Treasure and Magic Items","Prop and Handouts"),
                 v.names = "Times",
                 timevar = "Activities", 
                 times = c("Campaign and Worldbuilding","Story and Adventures","Combat Encounters","NPC Development","Exploration and Roleplay","Treasure and Magic Items","Prop and Handouts"), 
                 direction = "long")

    keeps <- c("Activities", "Times")
    l <- l[keeps]
    l[l=="None"] <- "None"
    l[l=="About 5 minutes"] <- "5 min"
    l[l=="About 15 minutes"] <- "15 min"
    l[l=="About 30 minutes"] <- "30 min"
    l[l=="About an hour"] <- "1 hr"
    l[l=="About two hours"] <- "2 hrs"
    l[l=="More than two hours"] <- "> 2 hrs"
    factor_labels <- c("None","5 min","15 min","30 min","1 hr","2 hrs","> 2 hrs")
    factor_charts <- c("Campaign and Worldbuilding","Story and Adventures","Combat Encounters","NPC Development","Exploration and Roleplay","Treasure and Magic Items","Prop and Handouts")

    l[,"Times"] <- factor(l[,"Times"], levels = factor_labels)
    l[,"Activities"] <- factor(l[,"Activities"], levels = factor_charts)
    row_count <- nrow(d)
    ggplot(l, aes(x=Times)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~Activities, nrow = 2, scales="free_x") + 
      xlab(paste("Preparation Time for Specific Activities out of",nrow(d),"Respondants")) +
      ylab("Number of respodants") +
      scale_y_continuous(expand=c(.1, 0)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
            axis.title.x=element_text(),
            axis.title.x=element_text())  +
      geom_text(aes(row_count=row_count, label = paste(round((..count../row_count)*100,0),"%", sep="")), 
                stat= "count", vjust=-.2, size=3)

  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("recalculate", "Recalculate"),
      checkboxGroupInput("frequency", "Frequency of Games",
                         unique(d[,2]), selected = unique(d[,2])),
      checkboxGroupInput("length", "Length of Games",
                         unique(d[,3]), selected = unique(d[,3])),
      checkboxGroupInput("locations", "Primary Locations",
                         unique(d[,5]), selected = unique(d[,5])),
      checkboxGroupInput("worlds", "Campaign Worlds",
                         unique(d[,6]), selected = unique(d[,6])),
      checkboxGroupInput("adventures", "Adventures",
                         unique(d[,7]), selected = unique(d[,7])),
      checkboxGroupInput("combat", "Combat Type",
                         unique(d[,8]), selected = unique(d[,8])),
      checkboxGroupInput("preptime", "Preparation Time",
                         unique(d[,9]), selected = unique(d[,9]))
    ),
    mainPanel(htmlOutput("textmain"),
              htmlOutput("text1"),
              htmlOutput("text2"),
              htmlOutput("text3"),
              htmlOutput("text4"),
              plotOutput("surveyPlot1"),
              plotOutput("surveyPlot2"),
              plotOutput("surveyPlot3"),
              plotOutput("surveyPlot4"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a [submit button](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/submitbutton-demo.html)?

Comment: That did it! Sorry, I'm pretty new to all of this R Shiny stuff. I got over my head with this one.